# Why does a new window open behind the current window using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Looked every where for this one and just cannot find the answer. I have a Page1.aspx page with a button (not a hyperlink or linkbutton just a standard button) that I need to open up another Page2.aspx page in another window/tab. Because it is a button with no target capability, I use the following code to open Page2 (known as MyInstructionsLinkPage.aspx) upon button click on Page1.

```
Dim InstructionFilePath As String = "http://MyInstructionsLinkPage.aspx"
Dim InstructionFileScript As String = "window.open('" & InstructionFilePath & "', 'Popup', '_newtab');"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "open", InstructionFileScript, True)
```

Works pretty well but it opens the MyInstructionsLinkPage.aspx behind my Page1 instead of in front of it. I tried .focus() but that didn't work, could be I had it in the wrong location in the code. If anyone can help please assist. So far you are all batting 1000 with questions I've had. Much Tanks.

Comment: I would try to avoid `window.open` [as much as possible](https://yaplex.com/blog/avoid-browser-pop-up-blockers). Can you not solve it with a normal link with `target=_blank`?

Comment: Let's begin with 2 things. 1: '_newtab' is not a valid window feature, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features you should remove it, and 2, do you have a browsing context called 'popup'? if not you can remove that as well.

Comment: For the first reply, the powers that be in management's dark side of the force have asked for a button look and not a hyperlink on this page, and they sign the checks. For the second reply, I removed the said code and it is working fine now. Thanks a bunch for the help.